# Regex to match on path after a known path in a URL

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get a perl regex to git me the path that appears after a certain path in a URL:

URLs to test against:

```
http://example.org/project/branches/new-feature
http://example.org/project/branches/new-feature/src
```

Given either of the above URLs, I want to capture "new-feature". Using the Perl regex below, I can the second URL but not the first.

```
echo $url | perl -pe 's|^.*/branches/(.*?)/.*$|\1|'
```

The issue is with the slash after "new-feature", which may or may not be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make the `/.*` optional. Use

```
perl -pe 's|^.*/branches/([^/]*)(?:/.*)?$|$1|'
```

Or

```
sed 's|^.*/branches/\([^/]*\)\(/.*\)\?$|\1|'
```

Or if you can afford a GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP '/branches/\K[^/]+'
```

The `(?:/.*)?` part matches 1 or 0 occurrences of  a `/` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars. The `sed` solution is identical, just the metacharacters are escaped since it is a BRE POSIX compliant pattern. In the `grep` solution, `/branches/\K` matches `/branches/` and the value is discarded after that and the only text returned is the one matched with `[^/]+` (one or more chars other than `/`).

See an [**online demo**](https://ideone.com/7HnjmS).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
perl -pe 's|.*?/branches/([^/]+).*|$1|'
```

Note

- `$1` not sed-like `\1`
- `[^\/]+` means: all character except `/`, and `+` means at least one occurence

Another solution :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if m|/branches/\K[^/]+|'
```

Comment: +1 because simpler is better, but you do not need the trailing `.*` at all. You do not need to escape the `/`.

Comment: Have you tried ? trailing `.*` is required. True for `/` thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried. My reading of the question, "*the path that appears after a certain path in a URL*" means the OP does not just want `new-feature` but the entire path including and following `new-feature`.

Comment: That's not how I understand the question, and that's why sample output is often more clear. OP said _Given either of the above URLs, I want to capture "new-feature"_

Comment: Except that if one knows that one wants the string `new-feature`, which is constant and immutable, there is no need for all these gymnastics.

Comment: Thanks to the down voters to explain what's wrong ? My output is identical to accepted answer...

Comment: There is only one down-vote ... I voted your answer up conditionally, then I retracted my vote. See also [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react). You may never know why the other person voted your answer down, and you should not care.

Comment: Yes, just curious to know why, that's all :)

Answer (score -2):

For PCRE PHP below code work fine for me.

/branches/(.+)//

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/5m2uQe/1) https://regex101.com/r/5m2uQe/1